# ffmpeg add new srt and delete old ones

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm struggling to find a one line command to merge new subtitle and delete existing ones from video file.

Example:

test1.mkv  (already contain softcoded subs, dont need them)

test1.srt (only subtitle that i want on video)

Working under ubuntu server 18.04 LTS 64bit

Any help?

SOLUTION UPDATE;

mkvmerge -o output.mkv -S 1.mkv --language 0:hrv --sub-charset 0:utf-8 1.srt

This will do the work

Comment: which version of ubuntu ?

Comment: Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS 64bit

Comment: can install mkvtoolnix ( see  my answer ) and run  mkvinfo on your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will recommand to use `mkvtoolnix`

A package exits for ubuntu https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/mkvtoolnix

with the right combination of `mkvextract` and `mkvmerge`  you can do what you want .

And you will use `mkvinfo` to display information about your file .

to install ...

```
apt-get install mkvtoolnix
```

to see a list of commands

```
dpkg -L mkvtoolnix | grep bin
```

and read `man mkvmerge` and `man mkvextract`

Comment: Working very well

Answer (score 1):

You have to map the new subtitles and map only the other streams from the original file.

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i test1.mkv -i test1.srt -c copy -map 0 -map -0:s -map 1 new.mkv
```

`-map 0` maps all streams from the original file, including subtitles. `-map -0:s` deletes the subtitle mapping. `-map 1` maps all streams from the 2nd input (test1.srt). All mapped streams are copied to new.mkv